# SQLite, merging two tables based on higher value in a column

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got two SQLite databases, each with a table that I need to keep synchronized by merging rows that have the same key. The tables are laid out like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE titles ( name    TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,
                      chapter TEXT               ,
                      page    INTEGER DEFAULT 1  ,
                      updated INTEGER DEFAULT 0  );
```

I want to be able to run the same commands on each of the two tables, with the result that for pairs of rows with the same *name*, whichever row has the greater value in *updated* will overwrite the other row completely, and rows which do not have a match are copied across, so both tables are identical when finished.

This is for an Android app, so I could feasibly do the comparisons in Java, but I'd prefer an SQLite solution if possible. I'm not very experienced with SQL, so the more explanation you can give, the more it'll help.

**EDIT**
To clarify: I need something I can execute at an arbitrary time, to be invoked by other code. One of the two databases is not always present, and may not be completely intact when operations on the other occur, so I don't think a trigger will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have [attached](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) the other database to your main database:

```
ATTACH '/some/where/.../the/other/db-file' AS other;
```

you can first delete all records that are to be overwritten because their `updated` field is smaller than the corresponding `updated` field in the other table:

```
DELETE FROM main.titles
WHERE updated < (SELECT updated
                 FROM other.titles
                 WHERE other.titles.name = main.titles.name);
```

and then copy all newer and missing records:

```
INSERT INTO main.titles
SELECT * FROM other.titles
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name
                   FROM main.titles);
```

To update in the other direction, exchange the `main`/`other` database names.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use a trigger.

i.e.

```
CREATE TRIGGER sync_trigger 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF updated ON titles
REFERENCING NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE updated_match;
DECLARE prime_name;
DECLARE max_updated;
BEGIN
    SET prime_name = n.name;
    ATTACH database2name AS db2;
    SELECT updated
    INTO updated_match
    FROM db2.titles t
    WHERE t.name=prime_name)

    IF updated_match is not null THEN
        IF n.updated > updated_match THEN
            SET max_updated=n.updated;
        ELSE
            SET max_updated=updated_match;
        END IF;

        UPDATE titles
        SET updated=max_updated
        WHERE name=prime_name;

        UPDATE db2.titles
        SET updated=max_updated
        WHERE name=prime_name;
    END IF;
END sync_trigger;
```

The syntax may be a little off. I don't use triggers all that often and this is a fairly complex one, but it should give you an idea of where to start at least. You will need to assign this to one database, exchanging "database2name" for the other database's name and then assign it again to the other database, swapping the "database2name" out for the other database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Normally I would say use a stored procedure, but SQLite3 doesn't support them. =(

Comment: Seems I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer, so consider this informal thanks for giving me so many things to Google all at once. ;)

Comment: This is not valid SQLite syntax.

Comment: @cl, i said in my post that i wasnt sure if the syntax was correct.

Comment: Also,  perhaps you could say what parts are invalid?

Comment: All the variables and flow-control statements, i.e., everything except the two UPDATEs. [SQLite's triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) are very restricted.

Comment: Are you sure? I am fairly certain that conditionals and variables are allowed in sqlite3 triggers. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @jonbonazza Have a look at the link in my last comment …